# Terraform: How to read resources from a list of objects

Tags: variables, data-structures, terraform

I need to read info from a structure data using Terraform and use this info to create any object in my environment.

I have this data structure that I must define as variable and read and use:

```
class_names = {
  servers = "my servers"
}

ip_addresses = {
  servers = {
    snmp_check = {
      1 = {
        mngmt0 = "192.168.0.1"
        hostname = "sito1.mydomain.local"
        proxy = "proxy1.mydomain.local"
      }
      2 = {
        mngmt0 = "192.168.0.2"
        hostname = "sito2.mydomain.local"
        proxy = "proxy1.mydomain.local"
      }
      3 = {
        mngmt0 = "192.168.0.3"
        hostname = "sito3.mydomain.local"
        proxy = "proxy1.mydomain.local"
      }
      4 = {
        mngmt0 = "192.168.0.4"
        hostname = "sito4.mydomain.local"
        proxy = "proxy2.mydomain.local"
      }
    }
    http_check = {
      1 = {
        mngmt0 = "127.0.0.1"
        hostname = "sito5.mydomain.local"
        proxy = "proxy3.mydomain.local"
      }
      2 = {
        mngmt0 = "127.0.0.1"
        hostname = "sito6.mydomain.local"
        proxy = "proxy1.mydomain.local"
      }
      3 = {
        mngmt0 = "192.168.0.5"
        hostname = "sito7.mydomain.local"
        proxy = "proxy2.mydomain.local"      
      }
      4 = {
        mngmt0 = "192.168.0.6"
        hostname = "sito8.mydomain.local"
        proxy = "proxy3.mydomain.local"      
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

How can set correctly my variable? I defined as below:

```
variable "class_id" {
  type = string
}

variable "class_names" {
  type = map
}

variable "instances" {
  type = list(object({
      site = string
      instance = string
    })
  )
}

variable "ip_addresses" {
  type = map
}
```

and I have a module to create instances:

```
module "server_host" {
  source        = "./hosts"
  instances     = local.server_instances
  class_id      = "server"

  class_names   = var.class_names
  ip_addresses  = var.ip_addresses
}
```

But I can't read correctly my data, I created the code below:

```
servers_instances = flatten([
    for site_key, site in var.ip_addresses["servers"] : [
      for instance_key, instance in site : {
        site = site_key
        instance = instance_key
      }
    ]
  ])
```

When I try to create my hosts with the code:

```
# create hosts
resource "zabbix_host" "host" {
  for_each = {
      for inst in var.instances : "${var.class_id}.${inst.site}" => inst
  }
  host = var.ip_addresses[var.class_id][each.value.site][each.value.instance]["hostname"]
  
  groups = [
    zabbix_hostgroup.hostgroup.id
  ]

  interface {
    type = "snmp"
    ip   = var.ip_addresses[var.class_id][each.value.site][each.value.instance]["mgmt0"]
    main = true
    port = 161
  }
}
```

I receive this error:

> Error: Duplicate object key
>
> on hosts/hosts.tf line 28, in resource "zabbix_host" "host": 26:
> for_each = { 27: #      for inst in var.instances : "${inst.site}" =>
> inst 28:       for inst in var.instances :
> "${var.class_id}.${inst.site}" => inst 29:   }    inst.site is
> "snmp_check"  var.class_id is "servers"

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you get any errors? What is `instances` variable? You are not using it anywhere. What are `var.ip_addresses` and the remaining of your locals and varaibles?

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for your reply. I updated the code. I need to read from the structure and create object in base of the value of host, proxy, ip

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the relation between your variables and these data structures. What is `class_id`, what is `instances`? I can see only definitions for `class_names` and `ip_addresses`. "can't read correctly my data," does not explain much. What exactly is happening? Any error messages? What do you get, and what do you want to get?

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for the reply and for your help. `class_id` is a String defined in main.tf, `instance` are a list of object that I need to fill in read from my data structure. I updated with more info